# One column equation in twocolumn document class

Tags: equations, two-column, revtex

I am writing  a paper (`revtex4-1`, reprint documentclass which I believe uses `twocolumn`) and need to have a long equation that needs to break the two column format. I've seen answers to this question using `multicol` but I can't use that class. So does anyone know how to do this from `twocolumn` class?

I have tried one way that makes the equation a `figure` but I can't get the alignment with the text correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `widetext` environment changes the formatting from two-column to one-column to better accommodate very long equations that are more easily read when typeset to the full width of the page:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{widetext}
\[
a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q
\]
\end{widetext}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Note that the `lipsum` package and commands is used only for adding dummy text.
[image: Example output of widetext latex command]

Comment: @UditaK.: The package `lipsum` and its command `\lipsum` is just added to provide some dummy/filler text.

Comment: I am getting following error when I try to compile it `! LaTeX Error: File 'widetext.sty' not found.` is it a normal cse?

Comment: There is no `widetext` package, it's an environment defined by `revtex4-1`.

Comment: Where is this document class revtex4-1? I have the same error than alper.