# Display a figure over 2 columns in a 2 column layout on a fixed position

Tags: floats, two-column

I would like to display a figure in a 2 column document, though the figure has to appear over the 2 columns on a fixed position. I tried this:

```
\begin{figure*}[H]
 \begin{center}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{features.JPG}
 \caption{Comparison of the classification algorithms with different feature space sizes}
 \label{features}
 \end{center}
\end{figure*}
```

But it does not work. Nothing really works when changing the H to h or ht etc ...

Anyone know the solution to this problem ?

Comment: "does not work" doesn't say *why*.  do you mean "on a fixed page", or the alignment of what's in the figure isn't what you want, or ... what?  please note that h or H would have no effect, since `figure*` can appear *only* at the *top* of a two-column page, not in the middle or at the bottom.

Comment: I want to have the figure on a fixed position. And the "why", I have no idea. It just isn't appearing on the right page

Comment: i should have said "doesn't say *how*" it doesn't work.  by "fixed position" do you mean somewhere other than at the top of the page?

Comment: If I use "H", it just disappears completely. If I use h it will appear on top of a page where it is not supposed to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on an interchange of comments, i infer that this `figure*` is wanted somewhere other than at the top of a page.

see lamport, p.197, section c.9.1: h and b are "not possible for double-column figures or tables in two-column format."

some other approaches have been developed that you might find useful, for example as presented in this question: [One column equation in twocolumn document class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26707/).