# To have abstract in the document class revtex?

Tags: abstract, article, revtex

I had to change my document class to **revtex4-1** to be able to have `\widetext` parameter for one of my equation, [discussion about implementation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26707/one-column-equation-in-twocolumn-document-class).
However, the abstract `\begin{abstract}...\end{abstract}` is not supported by this class.

My minimal code

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
\title{Hello world}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract} % abstract
The maximal
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

I get the errors

```
./article.tex:84: LaTeX Error: Environment abstract undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 \begin{abstract}
                      % abstract

./article.tex:8: LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{abstract}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.8 \end{abstract}
```

**How can you have abstract in revtex4-1?**
or
**How can you have widetext in *article* document class?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`revtex4-1`](http://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1) loads, amongst other packages, [`ltxfront`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/revtex/source/latex/revtex/ltxfront.dtx) to set up the front matter of the document. The following is taken from the [Author's guide for `revtex4-1`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/revtex/doc/latex/revtex/auguide/auguide4-1.pdf) (section **IV.4. The abstract**, p 7; part of section **IV. The Front Matter**):

> **IV.4. The abstract**
>
> An abstract for a paper is specified by using the `abstract` environment:
>
> ```
> \begin{abstract}
> Text of abstract
> \end{abstract}
> ```
>
> Note that in REVTeX 4.1 the abstract must be specified before the `\maketitle` command and there is no need to embed it in an explicit `minipage` environment.

So, use

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-1}% http://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1
\begin{document}
\title{Hello world}

\begin{abstract} % abstract
The maximal
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

It becomes apparent that `abstract` doesn't exist after a call to `\maketitle` when viewing the definition of `\frontmatter@maketitle` in [`ltxfront.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/revtex/source/latex/revtex/ltxfront.dtx):

```
\def\frontmatter@maketitle{%
  \@author@finish
  \title@column\titleblock@produce
  \suppressfloats[t]%
  \let\and\relax
  \let\affiliation\@gobble
  \let\author\@gobble
  \let\@AAC@list\@empty
  \let\@AFF@list\@empty
  \let\@AFG@list\@empty
  \let\@AF@join\@AF@join@error
  \let\email\@gobble
  \let\@address\@empty
  \let\maketitle\relax
  \let\thanks\@gobble
  \let\abstract\@undefined\let\endabstract\@undefined% ABSTRACT definitions removed
  \titlepage@sw{%
   \vfil
   \clearpage
  }{}%
}%
```

Comment: The Journal of Rheology wants to have the word "Synopsis" written centred over the abstract. Any idea how that could work?