# Abstract doesn't show up when I run the program

Tags: revtex, texworks, abstract, undefined, latex-project

I tried to make the abstract on TexWork, but it doesn't show up when I run the program. Although I used \maketitle, \newpage. It does not work. Could you help me point out which part that is not correct on my project, please?

```
\documentclass[mathptmx,12pt, letterpaper,prd]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{research project}
\author{Kim Phan}
\affiliation{Department of Physics \\ Edmonds College, 20000 68th Ave. Lynnwood, WA 98036}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
write the abstract here
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\begin{equation}
b^2 = c^2-a^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Here is the error:

! LaTeX Error: Environment abstract undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for the explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
...

l.11 \begin{abstract}

?

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx.  I don't know the answer, but I assume there are instructions for this document class that say how to enter an abstract.  You should follow that example.

Comment: With `revtex` the `abstract` environment should come before `\maketitle` which typesets the abstract as per [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139469/106162)

Comment: Because you have `\maketitle` twice. Remove the first.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked for me. I really appreciate it!