# Enclose blocks of selected text with large square brackets?

Tags: brackets

I have some long equations in my document. I want to add some square brackets so it is clear how the main text flows.

[image]

Here is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{onecolumn}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2]

\end{multicols}

\begin{equation}
+long\;equation 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-..................=
\end{equation}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[3]
\end{multicols}
\end{onecolumn}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't you provide the full equation? I wonder if it is really not possible to wrap it.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26707/one-column-equation-in-twocolumn-document-class

Answer (score 1):

I found the snippet [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2770):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,amsmath,multicol}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{multicols}
\par\noindent\rule{\dimexpr(0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep-0.4pt)}{0.4pt}%
\rule{0.4pt}{6pt}

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{R}^{(\text{d})}=
 g_{\sigma_2}^e
 \left(
   \frac{[\Gamma^Z(3,21)]_{\sigma_1}}{Q_{12}^2-M_W^2}
  +\frac{[\Gamma^Z(13,2)]_{\sigma_1}}{Q_{13}^2-M_W^2}
 \right)
 + x_WQ_e
 \left(
   \frac{[\Gamma^\gamma(3,21)]_{\sigma_1}}{Q_{12}^2-M_W^2}
  +\frac{[\Gamma^\gamma(13,2)]_{\sigma_1}}{Q_{13}^2-M_W^2}
 \right)\;. \label{eq:wideeq}
\end{equation}

\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}\hfill\rule[-6pt]{0.4pt}{6.4pt}%
\rule{\dimexpr(0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep-1pt)}{0.4pt}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[4-5]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]