# jou class apa6, problem with one column

Tags: document-classes, columns, documentclass-writing, journal

I have a problem trying to insert an equation cause is too large, so, I use the enviroment `multicols`, and `@twocolumnfalse`, but when I run the document, the precendent text its displayed in one column and the other is empty.

I try with the environment `widetext` but its produce the error "enviroment undefined", I'm learning this so I guess that I have a problem with the package, also I try to get the package `\usepackage{widetext}`, but its produce the error

`"File widetext.sty not found"`,

again I guess that I dont have the package in my computer but I don't know how to get it. This is the code that I'm using:

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa6}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{widetext}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

a lot of text

\begin{widetext}
\begin{equation}
EQUATION...
\end{equation}
\begin{widetext}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know `widetext` package as well. Where is `widetext` from? Off-topic: `hyperref` should be last package here (unless `cleveref` is used as well)

Comment: Ty for the recomendations. I was following this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26707/one-column-equation-in-twocolumn-document-class

and i tried only using the package lipsum, how is displayed, but i got the first error "enviroment undefined". As say one friend, could be an error with apa6, maybe the class doesn't allow the use of that environment.

Comment: Now, i try with the package cuted, it works untill the moment XD, i don't have the final document but seems that going to work, i would like if you can give me some advice with this package. Cause i told you, i'm learning this

Comment: Is there any news here?