# How can I prevent table to write over one column equation in twocolumn document class

Tags: equations, two-column

My goal is to write a one-column equation in a two-column document class. I have used the following answer: https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_make_equation_one_column_in_two_column_paper_in_latex .

> ```
> \usepackage{lipsum, mathtools, cuted}
> \begin{strip}
> \begin{equation}
>                         Your equation goes here
> \end{equation}
> \end{strip}
> ```

---

But when I use a table in between, it overwrites the equation. Is it possible to prevent this?

My sample code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{color, etoolbox, lipsum, mathtools, geometry}
\usepackage{cuted, textcomp, setspace, longtable, tabularx, array}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{singlespace}
        \begin{tabular}{ c c c }
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{singlespace}
\end{center}

\begin{strip}
    \[
        a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q
    \]
\end{strip}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        f(x)=
        \begin{cases}
            1 & \text{if}\ \text{x=0} \\
            0 & \text{otherwise}.
        \end{cases}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

AS you can see in the output, my table merges with the whole page equation:

[image]

Is it possible to prevent this, where tables and the long equation won't write on top of each other?

Please note that firstly I have tried `widetext` from this solution: [One column equation in twocolumn document class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26707/one-column-equation-in-twocolumn-document-class/26711#26711) ; but I have received following error: `! LaTeX Error: File 'widetext.sty' not found.`

Comment: It seems you can have up to 18 rows in your table without overwriting the equation.

Comment: Ah in my original file there is one table which has exact 19 rows I believe that one was causing an issue. Is it possible to extend 18 rows update 25 ?

Comment: I have no idea which parameter controls the number of allowed rows. May be with a longtable it would work?

Comment: I do have similiar issue with >18 rows algorithm definition

Comment: I found that if I added some text, such as `\lipsum[1]` before your code for the tabular and `\lipsum[1-4]` the end of your document it worked OK. I have no idea why but feel that it might have something to do with the definition of the `strip` environment (wherever that came from). BTW you have use several packages multiple times so your MWE needs clearing up.

Comment: I cleared up multiple packages. When I play around the order in some cases works too.  I put a wrong link for the approach I tried. Originally I was not able to use `widetext` package had this issue:(`File 'widetext.sty' not found`) so I was looking for another solution, `strip` came from some comment of a user I found in internet from here: https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_make_equation_one_column_in_two_column_paper_in_latex ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using `multicol` is a nice and easy workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
    \begin{singlespace}
        \begin{tabular}{ c c c }
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{singlespace}
\end{center}
\end{multicols}
\[
    a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q
\]
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        f(x)=
        \begin{cases}
            1 & \text{if}\ \text{x=0} \\
            0 & \text{otherwise}.
        \end{cases}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, this is *technically* not a two-column document. Instead, we can just take a one-column document and add the two-column parts around basically all text that is not your equation.